# Receiving key error on Networkx color_map

Tags: networkx, colormap

I'm having trouble getting the color_map to work with my networkx graph. It's fairly simply code but won't seem to work. I've looked through other similar threads but no the solutions don't seem to work.

I  have data that look like this:

```
edgelist_manual = [{'source': 'ABE', 'target': 'ATL', 'value': 851},
     {'source': 'ABE',  'target': 'BHM', 'value': 1},
     {'source': 'ABE',  'target': 'CLE',  'value': 805}]

edgelist = pd.DataFrame(edgelist_manual)

nodelist_manual = [{'source': 'ABE', 'value': '4807', 'group': 0},
     {'source': 'ABI',  'value': '2660', 'group': 4},
     {'source': 'ABQ',  'value': '41146',  'group': 2}]

nodelist = pd.DataFrame(nodelist_manual)
```

I run the code below, but my color_map keep screwing up. I just get a key error on the 'group' reference.

```
import itertools
import copy
import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

nodelist = pd.read_csv('final_nodes.csv')
edgelist = pd.read_csv('final_edges.csv')

g = nx.Graph()

for i, elrow in edgelist.iterrows():
    g.add_edge(elrow[0], elrow[1], attr_dict=elrow[2:].to_dict())
for i, nlrow in nodelist.iterrows():
    g.node[nlrow['source']].update(nlrow[1:].to_dict())

color_map = {0: 'r', 1:'b', 2:'r', 3:'b', 4:'r', 5:'b'}
colors = [color_map[g.node[node]['group']] for node in g]

nx.draw(g, node_color=colors)
ax = plt.gca()
ax.collections[0].set_edgecolor("#555555") 
plt.show()
```

The only difference from this and my code is that rather than creating the data manually I'm loading it from .csv. I've checked for trailing whitespaces on the feature labels but nothing. I don't understand indices well so I wonder if those are messing it up. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide the error message.  Does this code you've provided also have the same error as your original code?

Comment: Based on what you've said, I think the error is in the line `colors = [...]`, and it's giving an error for `g.node[node]['group']`.  An obvious step to take in debugging would be to see why it's giving you an error.  So why not print `g.node[node]` for a few nodes?  Given the error, this appears to not be what you expect it to be, perhaps once you see what it is, you'll figure out the error.

Comment: Yeah I get the same problem with the above code. (I did change ABI and ABQ to ABE just so it's sensible, but same error). When I print g.node[node] I get NameError: name 'node' is not defined

Comment: So when you're printing `g.node[node]`, what is `node` defined to be (hint - I don't think you've defined it before that test)?  It's defined in your list comprehension, but it won't be defined outside that.  You could for example do `for node in G:   print(g.node[node])`

Comment: It would still be helpful if you provided the full error message.  Please edit your question to include it.

Comment: Well it was a bit of a putzer. When I reworked the example above to have matching edges/nodes it worked--so I went back to my original data. It was helpful to print out g.node[node]. Ultimately the problem was that I didn't clean the data properly. There were references in the edgelist that for some reason didn't have a referent node, and this was causing the problem. I manually filled in the data and it worked. Appreciate the help. The code above *should* work fine with sensible inputs.